# Streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

I have a piece of code that is calculating some series:

```
object Problem7 extends App {
  lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i =>
  ps.takeWhile(j => j * j <= i).forall(i % _ > 0))

  val r = ps(10000)
  println(r)
}
```

here`ps` is of type collection Stream which is a variable actually but how its possible to call it like this `ps(10000)` as its not any method and I also have one more expression `val fs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)`, here also I'm a little ambiguous about how we are calling `fs.scanLeft(1)(_+_)` in the variable itself.Someone help!!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not declaring a method instead of a variable?

Comment: no reason just trying to understand how its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> here `ps` is of type collection Stream which is a variable actually but
>   how its possible to call it like this ps(10000) as its not any method

It's possible to call `ps(10000)` because `Stream` has an `apply` method (Inherited from `LinerSeqOptimized`):

```
/** Selects an element by its index in the $coll.
 *  Note: the execution of `apply` may take time proportial to the index value.
 *  @throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `idx` does not satisfy `0 <= idx < length`.
 */
def apply(n: Int): A = {
  val rest = drop(n)
  if (n < 0 || rest.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + n)
  rest.head
}
```

Calling `()` on any object in Scala will have the compiler looking for an `apply` method on the object. This is similar to how you can instantiate case classes without the `new` keyword, as the compiler generates `apply` and `unapply` automatically for you.

If we'll look at a simpler reproduce:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val ps: Stream[Int] = Stream.from(1, 1)
  val r = ps(1)
  println(r)
}
```

The compiler is actually doing:

```
val r = ps.apply(1)
```

Where `apply` for a collection usually looks up the element at index `i`:

```
scala> val ps: Stream[Int] = Stream.from(1, 1)
ps: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val r = ps(1)
r: Int = 2

scala> val x = ps.apply(1)
x: Int = 2
```

If you actually want to see what the compiler generates:

```
object Problem7 extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val ps: scala.collection.immutable.Stream = scala.`package`.Stream().from(1, 1);
      val r: Int = scala.Int.unbox(ps.apply(1));
      scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(r))
    };

    def <init>(): Problem7.type = {
      Problem7.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would u mind about a little explanation on this `val fs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)`, i know how scanleft works but how its calling `fs.scanLeft` is a little doubtful

Comment: It's due to the fact that `#::` is lazily evaluated. Your example won't compile without marking `fs` as `lazy`.

Comment: i rewrote above program `object Problem7 extends App {

    lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter {i =>
      println("i: = " + i)
      ps.takeWhile {j => println("j: = " + j);j * j <= i}.forall{ n => println("isnide forall i " + i + "and n: " + n);i % n > 0}}

    val r = ps(10)
    println(r)

}`, 1 doubt I have, when value of i (of inner stream)becomes 9 value of j (of outer Stream) changes to  3 but how??

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question,

```
lazy val fs:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)
```

The #:: is cons operator [Stream.cons](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) used for constructing streams. The parameter of [ConsWrapper](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$ConsWrapper) is a by-name parameter and hence it is evaluated lazily.

It is therefore valid to reference fs after the #:: operator. I think we have to change the val to lazy val, otherwise the scala compiler throws forward reference extends over definition of value fs.